# Can't install git in Mac OS! git-2.19.2

Tags: git

Failed to installed git in mac os. Version: git-2.19.2
Downlod site: https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/
“git-2.19.2-intel-universal-mavericks.pkg” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.

Comment: after it says cannot open, Setting > security&privacy. you will have an option saying something like open it anyways.

install xcode for MAC

Comment: All user do not needed Xcode! And it consume more storage!
Better Solution:
Open system preferences ->security & privacy ->General tab ->click the lock to make changes (downleft) -> select open anyway

Answer (score 11):

Solutions:
Open system preferences ->security & privacy ->General tab ->click the lock to make changes (downleft) -> select open anyway

Answer (score 0):

**FIX:** 
Here are all developer downloads 
Download the «Command Line Tools for Xcode», this includes Git.

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools

Answer (score 0):

Before install check if you have agreed to the Xcode license agreements running this command 'sudo xcodebuild -license'